How can I remove rust stains from outdoor vinyl flooring?
I have an outdoor patio on the second floor which receives runoff from the shingles.  It has been stained horribly over the past 3 years with this rust colored buildup all over it.
I tried using a pressure washer and it couldn't cut through the gunk to remove it.  I bought RustAid rust stain remover (outdoor), poured it on, let it soak, and tried to remove, no luck.  Anyone have advice or success stories about removing this type of stain?  The patio has a type of linoleum roll used from the best I can tell.




Unless it was made for outdoor use, that might be half of the problem.  Linoleum is usually used inside and with most stuff testing chemicals/cleaning should be done on a hidden section first.  I second it needing replacement.

You cannot clean what is horribly damaged.

I'm not sure why you'd try to salvage that material. You can plainly see in the third photo that it's badly degraded. It needs replacement.
If that is rust stain it has likely pervaded all the way through the flooring. You won't be able to remove it without removing the flooring. It could also be staining from below, depending on what substrate is underneath. At any rate, this isn't a cleaning job.

I think this is an instance of replacing it would be cheaper/faster/better than trying to fix it.
Better yet repalce it with something meant to be exposed to the elements.
